# XML animation working only once

Tags: android, android-animation

I tring to create an animation to my activity.

The animation working as it need to but it working only once.

```
Intent i = new Intent(a, UserDataActivity.class);
i.putExtra("userData", t);
a.startActivity(i);
a.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.spin_anim, R.anim.static_anim);
```

I starting the activity from other thread if it's matters.

a is a pointer to the main activity.

I know that the `overridePendingTransition` is working when calling the `startActivity` and the `finish` methods because of that I don't need to kill the calling acticity.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by running the code in the UI Thread

```
a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(a, UserDataActivity.class);
        // putting in the intent the user data
        i.putExtra("userData", t);
        a.startActivity(i);
        a.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.spin_anim, R.anim.static_anim);
    }
});
```

I would like if someone will explain me why this didn't work on other thread?